# How To Add RAC Libraries to XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to add Reactive Cocoa libraries to my Xcode project, but I can't. I'm trying to find some tutorial, because I can't understand the one in the Reactive Cocoa page.. How can I add this library to my proyect?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org). I wrote [a tutorial about it](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods).

Basically you install it via `[sudo] gem install cocoapods`, then create a Podfile on your project's folder:

```
platform :ios, '6.0' #deploy platform

pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
```

Then, run `pod install` and use the `.xcworkspace` it created.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite a bit down on the `README`, but the instructions for adding ReactiveCocoa to an Xcode project can be found here:

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#importing-reactivecocoa